# Initial value problem $y''=e^{2y}, y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Supposedly, it is possible to determine information about the constants of this IVP solution, without computing the solution of the differential equation.  Here's how I solve this.

Let $z=y'$. In brief, we then have the separable equation $$z\frac{dz}{dy}=f(y,z)=e^{2y}$$

and solving for $z$ $$z=\sqrt{e^{2y}+c}$$

which can be made into a separable equation and integrated. After playing around with the initial conditions, I did find that $c=0$. But this is a contradiction with the results of the second separable equation. Can we really solve $c$ before finding the explicit form of $y$?

Comment: Assuming your procedure for getting to $y'=f(x,y;c)$ is correct (I didn't check it), you can get $c$ from the initial data, since $y'(x_0)=f(x_0,y(x_0);c)$ is an algebraic equation for $c$ once $x_0,y(x_0)$ and $y'(x_0)$ are all given.

Comment: I just checked over your procedure and it looks like you did it right.

Comment: This was a question asked a few days ago,, feel free to review the [answers there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035183/how-do-we-solve-y-e2y/4035196#4035196)

Comment: " this is a contradiction with the results of the second separable equation": can you explain ?

Comment: After I integrate $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2y}+c}}$, I end up with  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}$ as a factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035183/how-do-we-solve-y-e2y/4035196#4035196), we see that we need to take the $+$ of the square root and the answer will be case $3$ where  $C_1=0$. Thus the answer is

$$y=-\log(1-x)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $y'' = e^{2y}$. Multiplying by $y'$ you have $y'y'' = y'e^{2y}$, which you can integrate:
\begin{align*}
\int y'y''\, dt &= \int y' dy' \\
&=\tfrac{1}{2}(y')^2 + C
\end{align*}
where $C$ is a constant of integration.
On the other side you have
\begin{align*}
\int y' e^{2y}\, dt &= \int e^{2y}\, dy \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}e^{2y} + D
\end{align*}
with $D$ also a constant of integration. Combining you end up with
\begin{equation*}
(y')^2 = e^{2y} + 2E
\end{equation*}
where $E = C + D$.
So if you happen to know $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, you have your $E$.

Answer (score 0):

By integration from $0$ to $y$, $$2zz'=2e^{2y}\implies z^2-z_0^2=e^{2y}-1$$

and

$$z=y'=e^y$$ (the solution $z=-e^y$ is not possible).

Then integrating between $0$ and $x$,

$$-e^{-y}+e^{-y_0}=x$$

or

$$y=-\log(1-x).$$